# Rendering a cross in ASCII art

Tags: haskell, ascii-art

I've recently tried to write my functions by using composition. But this one, `renderCross'` is especially difficult to convert fully. How would I write this composition point free?  It's the `n` that I'm trying to make disappear. I've tried using `<*>`, and [pointfree.io](https://pointfree.io/) uses `liftA2` (but this results in very ugly code) so I would believe I'm at least somewhat close.

Maybe I could use the Reader monad, but would that be too complicated?

```hs
renderCross :: Int -> String
renderCross = spread . unlines . flip renderCross' [""]
  where
    renderCross' :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
    renderCross' n = edge n . vert n . horiz n . mid n . horiz n . vert n . edge n

edge :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
edge i s = s ++ [space i ++ "ooo"]

vert :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
vert i s = s ++ replicate (i - 2) (space i ++ "o|o")

horiz :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
horiz i s = s ++ [horiz' ++ "|" ++ horiz']
  where
    horiz' = replicate i 'o'

mid :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
mid i s = s ++ [intercalate (replicate (i - 1) '-') ["o", "o", "o"]]

space :: Int -> String
space n = replicate (n - 1) ' '
```

EDIT:

```hs
-- spread out word, i.e. add a space between each character
spread = intersperse ' '
```

Comment: What's the implementation for `spread`? AFAICT, it's not in base, and I can't find a matching one on Hoogle. Would be helpful for trying out what the function does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use the Reader monad to get a pointfree version of `renderCross'`, like this:

```
renderCross :: Int -> String
renderCross = spread . unlines . renderCross' [""]
  where
    renderCross' ::  [String] -> Int -> [String]
    renderCross' = runReader . (edge >=> vert >=> horiz >=> mid >=> horiz >=> vert >=> edge)

edge :: [String] -> Reader Int [String]
edge s = asks (\i -> s ++ [space i ++ "ooo"])

vert :: [String] -> Reader Int [String]
vert s = asks (\i -> s ++ replicate (i - 2) (space i ++ "o|o"))

horiz :: [String] -> Reader Int [String]
horiz s = asks (\i -> let horiz' = replicate i 'o' in s ++ [horiz' ++ "|" ++ horiz'])

mid :: [String] -> Reader Int [String]
mid s = asks (\i -> s ++ [intercalate (replicate (i - 1) '-') ["o", "o", "o"]])

space :: Int -> String
space n = replicate (n - 1) ' '
```

This does the following:

- The functions `edge`, `vert`, `horiz`, and `mid` now return a `Reader Int [String]`, their implementations use `ask` to access the `Int` instead of using a plain function argument
- `renderCross'` doesn't use function composition anymore, but [`(>=>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-), aka Kleisli composition. It's basically the same, but since you have functions that have a monadic return value, the simple function composition doesn't work anymore. Note that the order of composition is reversed compared to `(.)`. You just don't see it in this example because it's the same forwards or backwards.
- `renderCross'` uses `runReader` to feed in the argument to the composed function. Text-book application of the reader monad.
- the type of `renderCross'` is different to your example. I switched the two arguments, to simplify the pointfree implementation. This has the additional benefit that you don't need to `flip` it in the implementation of `renderCross`.

So yes, it's possible to write a pointfree version of the function by using `Reader`. Is it better than the original version? I'm not sure. It's definitely cool to have a pointfree implementation but you have to pay the price of more concepts that are used (`Reader`, `(>=>)`). Plus, in my experience, pointfree functions tend to be harder to understand than equivalent implementations with explicit arguments.